# Java: Why is this a Deadlock when lock is null?

Tags: java, multithreading

I was having a deadlock scenario in my code. I reproduced the scenario with the following test code (look at the line number comments too).

I have one `ExecuterService` which takes 3 tasks, 2 tasks have a synchronized block over the same object which is not initialized it should have the `null` value.

`synchronized(null){}` is not allowed in java so I was expecting an error at `line-2`. However, this executed with a deadlock. i.e. the first two tasks were kept waiting by the 3rd task. (see Output-1)

Now If I change `line-1` to `Object lock = new Object();` The code will work flawlessly without any deadlock(Output-2). I am just wondering what exactly is happening with JVM when we provide an uninitialized mutex object? Looks like JVM is creating a static copy for the same, which shared by all the tasks. Hence the deadlock

```
public class Test {
    Object lock; //line -1
    Integer a = 10;

    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        new Test().doIt();
    }

    public void doIt() {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3);

        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (Test.this.lock) { //line -2
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Test.this.a = (int) Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    System.out.println(a + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                }
            }
        });

        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                synchronized (Test.this.lock) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000 * 5);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    Test.this.a = (int) Thread.currentThread().getId();
                    System.out.println(a + " " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

                }
            }
        }

        );

        service.submit(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Test.this.a = (int) Thread.currentThread().getId();
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1 * 1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    System.out.println(a + " Main");
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

**Output -1**

```
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
.
.
.
```

**Output-2**

```
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
11 Main
9 9
9 Main
9 Main
9 Main
9 Main
9 Main
10 10
10 Main
10 Main
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't have a deadlock - there's an error just as you expected. The first and second tasks will throw `NullPointerException`, leaving only the third task running.

You can see this if you surround the body of `run()` in a `try`/`catch` statement.

Comment: Ah got it, that exception is never caught and printed. Got it. That so stupid of me...

Comment: @MangatRaiModi: Well, it's unfortunate that it's so silent - it's a recipe for problems, IMO. It would be nice if there were an easy way of registering an error listener or something... You could check the `Future` returned by submit to see that it's done, but not the error... you could get that by calling `get()` of course.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Unchecked Exceptions are always pain.

Answer (score 3):

The exception is thrown on the executor thread and not visible unless you catch or query it. For example you could write:

```
Future<?> f = service.submit(new Runnable() { ... }
```

and at the end of main:

```
try {
  f.get();
} catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

That will show you the NPE.